# python 3 regular expression replace words in a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to replace the word "ROAD" with "RD" in all occurrences in the below list addr by using a seperate method `subt()` and print the new address.

**Note: using regular expression module in python3**

```
def subst():
    addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library function of python called `replace()`. Just follow following the code:

```
for (index, s) in enumerate(addr):
    addr[index] = s.replace(' ROAD', ' RD')
```

This two line of code will change all the occurence of `ROAD` to `RD`.

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot:-) Is it possible to replace using regex module??

Comment: @VishalS... Well, its not important to use regex everytime.. this code is working, so where is the problem.. BTW the most efficient way to thank someone who answers you on stack overflow is by giving a checkmark on his answer, if you think that this answer helped you then give this answer a checkmark.. Happy to help you

Comment: Thanks a lot:-) Got it!!